# EclipseLink - Oracle Stored Procedure call newbie problem

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I'm in charge of a task which I believe should be simple, but as I never did it before I have some trouble with it. I have succesfully created an EJB 3 project using EclipseLink which will call a number of stored procedures from an Oracle database. I've configured the datasource correctly, I can connect and execute simple stored procedures and functions (without parameters and returning a cursor); however, I am currently unable to execute stored procedures with parameters.

I'm using the EclipseLink wiki as a reference http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Basic_Query_API_(ELUG) .

The code is:

```
StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
call.setProcedureName("p_environment.startSession");

List<String[]> args = new ArrayList<String[]>();
args.add(new String[] { "user", "ae01403" });
args.add(new String[] { "application", "app_code" });
args.add(new String[] { "locale", "it_IT" });

for (String[] pair : args) {
    call.addNamedArgumentValue(pair[0], pair[1]);
}

DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery(call);
for (String[] pair : args) {
    query.addArgument(pair[0]);
}
```

Based on database documentation, as I have no access to the database itself, the procedure takes 3 VARCHAR IN parameters of the specified name. I then call the executeQuery method on the active session, but receive the "Wrong type or number of arguments" error. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The stored procedure signature, as per documentation, is:

```
p_environment.startSession(as_user        IN VARCHAR2, 
                           as_application IN VARCHAR2, 
                           as_locale      IN VARCHAR2);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: edited my post with more accurate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `call.addNamedArgumentValue(pair[0], pair[1]);` sounds strange.

Don't you need to do this instead ?

```
call.addNamedArgument(procedureParameterName, argumentFieldName, argumentType);
```

It enables the mapping between your stored procedure parameters and the args you want to use.

For example, for you, it gives :

```
call.addNamedArgument(procedureUserParameterName, "user", String.class);
call.addNamedArgument(procedureUserParameterName, "application", String.class);
call.addNamedArgument(procedureUserParameterName, "locale", String.class);
```

You keep this :

```
DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery(call);
for (String[] pair : args) {
    query.addArgument(pair[0]);
}
```

Then to call your Stored Procedure :

```
Session session = jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
List args = new ArrayList();
args.add(“ae01403”);
args.add(“app_code”);
args.add(“it_IT”);
List results = (List) session.executeQuery(query, args);
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, no luck. I think call.addNamedArgumentValue(pair[0], pair[1]); does the same thing than passing a list of arguments as a parameter to session.executeQuery(), binding values to parameters. Type defaults to String when not specified and I intended to use the same name for procedure parameter name and argument field name anyways. The error and generated code were also the same... I'm at a loss. I edited the question to include the stored procedure signature.